# Highlight Duplicate in Column and same time need value in Column T

Tags: excel, vba

I have written some code that, when there is a Duplicate value in Column A, then True = False would be there, same as we do in Excel, `A1`=`A2`, until the last row where we have data in A.

I am unsure how to find the last row , so i have coded the range up to `T9000`, but there could be data up to `T3500`, or sometimes `T15000`.

```
Range("A1:A5000").Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Dup"
Range("T2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C[-19]=RC[-19]"
Range("T3").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range("S1048576").Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Range("T9000").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
Selection.FillDown
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure, what you are looking for. To identify the last row in a column, you can simply use the following code: `lLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row` . Please note, that the column needs to be adapted and the result is stored into a LONG variable (integer would work to ~32.000).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure about the placement of your Dup should it be cell A1? The rest of your code can be contracted by using your last row variable.

```
lastRow = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
```

Contracted code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindDups()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook                        'Variable assignments
    Set wsSource = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    lastRow = wsSource.Cells(wsSource.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find last row by coming from the bottom of the sheet and finding last used cell in column

    With wsSource
        .Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "Dup"
        .Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
        .Range("T2:T" & lastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-19]=R[-1]C[-19],""Duplicate"", RC[-19])"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, i have come through the below Code now i am getting "Duplicate" in Coumn t , however where the value is Unique i am getting that cell as blank , when code should i insert so i can get Orignal in blank cells                                                        Dim matchFoundIndex As Long
Dim iCntr As Long
lastRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row
For iCntr = 1 To lastRow
If Cells(iCntr, 1) <> "" Then
matchFoundIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(iCntr, 1), Range("A1:A" & lastRow), 0)
If iCntr <> matchFoundIndex Then
Cells(iCntr, 20) = "Duplicate"
End If
End If
Next

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. But see if edit is what you want.

Comment: i mean i am getting the word Duplicate where that value in Column A is more than once , what changes i need to make to get Original where the Value in A Column is Single , please review the above Code.

Comment: do you mean the word "Original"? The code edit at present, will return the first occurrence of the value in ColA by value and after that return the word duplicate. If you had A1 = "A" A2="A" A3="B" A4 = "A", what result would you expect to see in T1,T2,T3,T4?

Comment: thank you https://stackoverflow.com/users/6241235/qharr , i have made the changes and it worked what i needed , appreciate your efforts.

Comment: below is the code , when i Run the macro , i changes my Header (DUP)  to unique  . why it is please                           Dim lastRow As Long
Dim matchFoundIndex As Long
Dim iCntr As Long
lastRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row
For iCntr = 1 To lastRow
If Cells(iCntr, 1) <> "" Then
matchFoundIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(iCntr, 1), Range("A1:A" & lastRow), 0)
If iCntr <> matchFoundIndex Then
Cells(iCntr, 20) = "Duplicate"
Else
Cells(iCntr, 20) = "Unique"
End If
End If
Next

Comment: Sachin: start at T2  i.e. For iCntr = 2 To lastRow

Comment: i tried the above code with some changes , need to sort the column D and then Duplicate and Unique should be pop up in Column AO  , please help below is the amended code

Comment: Dim lastRow As Long
Dim matchFoundIndex As Long
Dim iCntr As Long
lastRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row
For iCntr = 2 To lastRow
If Cells(iCntr, 2) <> "" Then
matchFoundIndex = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(iCntr, 1), Range("D1:D" & lastRow), 0)
If iCntr <> matchFoundIndex Then
Cells(iCntr, 41) = "Duplicate"
Else
Cells(iCntr, 41) = "Unique"
End If
End If
Next

Comment: Hi Sachin, I will have a look tomorrow morning.

Comment: @Sachin: 1) Are you looking in column A for duplicates or are you now sorting column D and looking for duplicated in column D and putting the result in AO? 2) Are you restricted to using a solution with matchFoundIndex rather than the original solution format i gave?

Comment: i am looking for Duplicate in Column D and the results should be in Column AO,     also Shall you please make me clear about (icntr,1) , why we use this in the above

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6241235/qharr Did you get a change to my query please ?

Comment: (icntr,1) is where icntr is a variable indicating the row part of a cell reference where the reference is Cells(row, column). The 1 means column 1 so "A". This is looping the rows in column A as icntr is incrementing e.g. is row 2 when inctr = 2 then 3 then 4 etc. So if you are looping column D (4) this beceomes Cells(inctr, 4).